# Javascript function is not working I'm using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

After adding my code, other javascript functions within the .js file stopped working too. So I'm thinking it might be a problem with the code. I'm also trying to implement a codeigniter php code within the .js file.

This is the added function in .js file:

```
function confirmDelete(del, id){
    var r=confirm("Confirm delete?");
    if (r==true){
        <?php redirect(base_url('home/delete/')+del+"/"+id, 'refresh'); ?>
    }
    else{
        <?php redirect(current_url(), 'refresh'); ?>
    }
};
```

This is how I used it in the view file:

```
<a href="" onclick="confirmDelete('event', <?php echo $record['id']; ?>);">X</a>
```

Comment: Your PHP code will not work in `*.js` file, write JS code in `*.php` file to include PHP in JS

Comment: js don`t understand php tags or php code, this is the problem in your method.

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't seem to read the js code, it just goes directly to the php code within the js file. In short, it just keeps on refreshing to home.

Answer (score 0):

Is the .js file generated by php? If not, you can't use PHP code there. Try this to confirm the JavaScript function is working fine:

```
function confirmDelete(del, id){
    var r=confirm("Confirm delete?");
    if (r==true){
        alert('deleted!');
    }
    else{
        alert('not deleted!');
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, it didn't work, sir. It's also not generated by php.